# How to hide the class' properties and methods when defining and using one protocol in the .h file for Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

For example: my .h file is like below:

```
// .h file
@protocol pageUpdateDelegate
-(void)pageUpdateMethod2;
@end

@interface ClassA
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger page;
-(void)pageUpdateMethod1;
@end
```

I want to provide this pageUpdateDelegate protocol to other people.
However, I don't want my ClassA's property and method been revealed and used by others.
But I will definitely use the ClassA a lot.
Then how can I do to protect my property and methods in the .h file?
I just want others to use the protocol part. Thanks.

Comment: One option is always just creating a header file simply for the protocol

Comment: Just like class names, protocol names should be being with uppercase letters.

Comment: if you want to hide methods and properties from others means you don't allow to access it from outside of class. if yes then only in .m file write those methods so no one access it.

Comment: Yeah, I know we can move protected property and method into to the .m file to prevent them been revealed. However, is there any way to prevent them revealed when somebody only wants to use the protocol?